# Calculating device acceleration - short distances - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, accelerometer

I'm starting a new Android project - I'm looking for a way to calculate the device's acceleration.
The main thing is to calculate the table's kinetic friction coefficient.
I've got the device's angle and I turned on vibration (In order to find the exact angle where the static friction becomes kinetic).

Using GPS is no good...

Thanks!! (: